# Fabric JS bounding box to "hug" / surround selected object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, bounding-box

Hi is it possible to create a Fabric JS bounding box that doesn't display a rectangle around the selected object, but rather displays a line that "hugs" the selected object. For example a circle object gets a circular bounding box around it when selected, and other more complex shapes as well. I have read through the documentation and don't have any code to display since I am not sure how to start tackling this problem.

Comment: What would a non-rectangular bounding box look like exactly? If you're looking to have control points for each vertex, the new controls api in v4 should help http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the bounding box of an object will always be a Rectangle, and you cannot change it to another shape.

What you can do is play a bit with that bounding box, like in the fabricJS [demo here](https://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle), but you won't be able to get a circular box.